# Split each character in a string into an array so long as theres a space?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a little side project and I need to turn a string like this:
ab c de f g

to an array like so: ab,c,de,f,g
I have tried using

```
     Dim string As String = "ab c de f g" 
     Dim charArray() As Char = string.ToCharArray
```

but that splits EVERY character into the array (a,b, ,c, ,d,e, ,f, ,g), how can I make it only split between the spaces?

Comment: Split is your answer.... see string.Split....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a job for [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 Dim source As String = "ab c de f g" 
 Dim result AS String() = source.Split(" "c)  
 For Each s in result
      Console.WriteLine(s)
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read the entire string and use the space as delimeter. Means: create a pointer to the string and skip till you find character, then use strncpy, to copy the substring you need. repeat it while(*ptr).

Comment: Did you see the tag VB.NET?

Comment: oh, sorry ... didnt see that